# Django/react Dockerfile stages not working together

Tags: node.js, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a multistage Dockerfile for a Django/React app that is creating the following error upon running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
backend_1  |   File "/code/myapp/manage.py", line 17
backend_1  |     ) from exc
backend_1  |          ^
backend_1  | SyntaxError: invalid syntax
backend_1 exited with code 1
```

As it stands now, only the frontend container can run with the two below files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.12
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code
RUN pip install -r ./myapp/requirements.txt


FROM node:10

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json file into our app directory
# COPY /myapp/frontend/package.json /app

COPY /myapp/frontend /app
# Install any needed packages specified in package.json
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

# COPY /myapp/frontend /app
# COPY /myapp/frontend/src /app
CMD npm start
```

docker-compose-yml:

```
version: "2.0"
   
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    command: python /code/myapp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - reactdrf
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - reactdrf

networks:
  reactdrf:
```

Project structure (relevant parts):

project (top level directory)

- api (the django backend)
- frontend

  - public
  - src
  - package.json
- myapp

  - manage.py
  - requirements.txt

docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile

---

The interesting thing is when commenting out one service of the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml or the other, the part left runs fine ie. each service can run perfectly fine on its own with their given syntaxes.  Only when combined do I get the error above.

I thought this might be a docker network issue (as in the containers couldn't see each other) but the error seems more like a location issue yet each service can run fine on their own?

Not sure which direction to take this, any insight appreciated.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how multi-stage Dockerfiles work. Only the final stage has any impact on the image produced by `docker build`. The other stages only provide content that is available in the final stage if you do something like `COPY --from=<stage_name> ...`. A `COPY` directive without `--from` doesn't copy from a previous stage; it just tries to look up files in your host filesystem (and would probably fail, since an absolute path like `/myapp` isn't going to be inside your build context).

Comment: Yes you are correct, for some reason I thought there could only be one Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

Misconfigured my project heres what I did to resolve it:
Separate the frontend and backend into their own Dockerfiles such that the 1st part of my Dockerfile above (backend) is the only part of the Dockerfile remaining in the root directory and the rest of it is in its own Dockerfile in /frontend.

Updated the docker-compose.yml web service build path to point to that new location,

```
... 
web:
    build: ./myapp/frontend
...
```

seems to build now sending data from backend to frontend.

What I learned - multiple Dockerfiles for multiple services.  Gets glued together in docker-compose.yml instead of combining them into one Dockerfile.

Comment: Question, did you need to update the settings.py file to point at the deployed react app? I am trying to get my Dockerized Django backend to talk to my Dockerized React frontend.

Comment: @colmulhall The only things I added to my settings were the CORS details for the frontend (whitelist and some middleware). I used [this](https://medium.com/@gazzaazhari/django-backend-react-frontend-basic-tutorial-6249af7964e4) as a rough guide for the react portion.  As far as getting the back/frontend working together, I think that is more related to the compose file.  The only relationship I have in a working deployment is the "depends on" section in compose, no "networks" designation was needed (everything else is the same as originally included above).

Comment: Dear Jocham,
I am also trying to deploy my react and django app, completely decoupled.
Which hosting did you use?
Do you have a docker compose file for production and a different docker compose file for test?
Did you followed a guide?

Comment: @Lobbel I just have a Dockerfile for my frontend, and another for the django project in the project root.  The django one uses a requirements.txt file to install dependencies.  Only guide I used was the one I mentioned in a comment above. Just using the single compose file that I also included in the OP, running locally